# MySqli prepared statements not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I wrote a PHP class that functions as expected on my dev machine, but when I upload it to my server, it doesn't work. After a lot of tinkering, I found something that I can't explain.

Essentially, This does NOT work it returns absolutely nothing:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT sh_value FROM sh_usermeta WHERE sh_key='points' AND sh_user_id=1");
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($res);
$sql->fetch();
$sql->close();
```

But, this does return the expected values:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT sh_value FROM sh_usermeta WHERE sh_key='points' AND sh_user_id=1");
$result->fetch_object();
```

So, the statements are the same, but for some reason it only works if I use "query()." Just as a note, my first codeblock is a simplified example (that I have verified does not work). I want to use prepared statements, because in some other cases I want to be able to bind parameters, such as usernames.

Again, the prepared statements worked on my dev environment, but on my server (PHP version: 5.2.17, MySql version: 5.0.51a) it doesn't.

Also, to clarify, I put in error checks after every sql operation, and it never once printed out an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit** OK, this confuses things a little more. I have another prepared statement that IS working. The only difference, as far as I can tell, is that it's accessing a different table. I don't understand this at all :S

Answer (score 0):

The query does not work because of a MySQL-error.
`key` is a MySQL keyword ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html)) and must be escaped:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT value FROM usermeta WHERE `key`='points' AND user_id=1");
```

#### Further hint

You can always escape the fields (or let a library do the job for you) to prevent such name collisions (further common examples are `option`, `order`, ...)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't think of that when writing my question. In my actual code, I have a prefix before everything, but it just seemed like a waste of time to write it out. I'll edit my question to reflect that. Also, I threw in error checks everywhere, but none of them were tripped.

Comment: What does "nothing" in the original question mean? `null`?

Comment: I tried doing a var_dump on the result, and it didn't output anything. That is what I mean when I say it returned "nothing". **Yes, I just checked, the result is null**

Comment: Did you confirm, that an actual row with user_id = 1 and key = points does exist on the server?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the original question. If I perform the statement using "query()" then it works and the expected result is returned. As soon as I try to do it with a prepared statement though, the result is null.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Could you provide the schema of the table? mysqli handles some data types differently with or without prepared statements.

Comment: Well, it only uses bigint and varchar. Although I just noticed that the varchar is using latin1 collation, whereas the rest of it is using utf8. That shouldn't stop me from getting results though, should it? If anything, it would just make my results incomprehensible.